# How to use substring_index in match against

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a sql query to pull all the relevant "Tennis Gifts" products using mysql match against ( index:fulltext ) but i am getting following error when using the substring_index to get only the category part from product_attributes to match against `Tennis Gifts` string

product_attributes value = {"category":"Tennis > Gifts > Necklace", "seasons":{"months":["January","February"]}}

```
select product_code
from products
where match(substring_index(substring_index(product_attributes, 'category', -1), '"', 1)) against ('Tennis Gifts' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

## Error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(substring_index(product_attributes, 'category', -1), '"', 1)) ' at line 3

How can i match only category value against search term, appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no PHP in this question at all. The `php` tag is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
select product_code
    from products
    where match(substring_index(substring_index(product_attributes, 'category', -1), '\"', 1)) 
    against ('Tennis Gifts' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion but i am still getting the Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(substring_index(product_attributes, 'category', -1), '\"', 1)) aga' at line 3